# How to run Scheduler add-on at Heroku once per month?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, heroku, cron, scheduled-tasks

In the selection of how often I want to run my action the only options are "Daily", "Hourly" and "Every 10 minutes".

Thanks! I want to run the Scheduler for my Rails 3.1 app.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not an elegant solution, but you could schedule it to run daily and check the date is the first of the month at the start of your job before actually doing the work.

Comment: Well, it looks like a possible solution, but probably not optimal. In any case, currently I haven't any other idea how to do, so I will do it this way. Thanks.